# How to get path from file variable in Symfony3

Tags: php, file, path, upload, symfony

I'm working on a site using Symfony3 and you can upload an image for your profile. But I want to check if the image really is an image and if the file is less than 2MB.

The input element already has an `accept='image/*'` attribute, so it's only server sided my question.

Here's the code I use to check if the image is really an image less than 2MB:

```
if(getimagesize($user->getAvatarFile()) !== false) {
    if ($organisation->getAvatarFile()->getSize() > 2000000){
        $this->addFlash('error', "Image too large!");
    }
} else {
    $this->addFlash('error', "File is not an image!");
}
```

the `avatarFile` from a user actually is that file, but how do I get it's path so I can use `getimagesize`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the symfony doc about [File](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html) (which is the same as [Image](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Image.html), except for mimeType).

There are some constraintslike [maxSize](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#maxsize), which can be usefull.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class User
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Image(
     *     maxSize = "2M",
     *     maxSizeMessage= "The file is too large ({{ size }} {{ suffix }}). Allowed maximum size is {{ limit }} {{ suffix }}."
     * )
     */
    protected $AvatarFile;
}
```

EDIT: If you only want to get the file path, before move it, you can use the [getClientOriginalName](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getClientOriginalName) function. Note that it won't return you the full file path as it may be excpected, since on upload, file are renamed on your /tmp dir, and then, moved (and so, renamed if needed).

Comment: Alright, I'll try it. I'll let you now if it works. Thank you.

Comment: When it's uploaded and the form is submitted, I still get this ````Warning: POST Content-Length of 5516431 bytes exceeds the limit of 3145728 bytes in Unknown on line 0````

Comment: Seeing this message, 5.516.431 > 3.145.728. So there is an error. What did you tryed to upload, and which size? Also, make sure that your php.ini didn't got a low limit on upload size too.
EDIT: On your php ini, chech values`upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. Don't forget to restart apache after.

Comment: If I change those limits to 2M, I still get that warning. How do I "catch" that warning and show it in a more user-friendly message?

Comment: The limit should be above 2M, as this error message seems to tell you that you are trying to upload a 5M file, and limit is set to 3M.
Assert constraints should allow you to display some error message

Comment: Sorry to keep on asking questions, but if I increase the upload and post limit, there is still a possibility to upload a file even bigger than the already increased upload/post limit? So I will still get that warning?

Comment: php.ini parameters are the final limit, whatever you set in your code (since it's apache side). So, as far as I know, it isn't possible to upload a bigger file than limits defined in your php.ini. So you need to set a bigger limit than the one in your code.

Comment: Ok I get it. Thank you very much